# Validate records order in shell script

Tags: scripting

Input file
Header
1
2
3
1
2
3
Trailer
We need to validate input file line first character like 1 2  3 like these sequence or not. Can you please help me with scripts

Comment: Can you provide more information? like which shell are you using and what code have you tried to solve this problem

Comment: I have input file like below
Header.
1aaaaaa
2aasss
3aaadddf
1sdfffgghh
2ddfffff
3bbbbbbb
Trailer
I need to validate input file like line first character 1, 2, 3 sequence is present or not. I have to validate like this.

Comment: You need to put your comment contents into the question itself so that anyone who has the same problem or is trying to help can find all the information necessary in one place.